# Java 8 stream grouping a List<Map<>> by the same <Key, Value> to a new List<Map<>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have a `List<Map<String,String>>`
such as:

```
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("date", "2020.1.5");
m1.put("B", "10");

Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("date", "2020.1.5");
m2.put("A", "20");

Map<String, String> m3 = new HashMap<>();
m3.put("date", "2020.1.6");
m3.put("A", "30");

Map<String, String> m4 = new HashMap<>();
m4.put("date", "2020.1.7");
m4.put("C", "30");

List<Map<String, String>> before = new ArrayList<>();
before.add(m1);
before.add(m2);
before.add(m3);
before.add(m4);
```

My expect result is to generate a new List map, which is grouped by date , and all the entry set in the same date would be put together, like:

```
[{"A":"20","B":"10","date":"2020.1.5"},{"A":"30","date":"2020.1.6"},{"C":"30","date":"2020.1.7"}]
```

I tried with the following method, but always not my expect result.

```
stream().flatmap().collect(Collectors.groupingBy())
```

**Some Additional Comments for this problem:**

I worked this out with for LOOP, but the application hangs when the list size is about 50000, so I seek a better performant way to do this. Java 8 stream flat map is a perhaps way as far as I know.
So the key point is not only to remap this but also with the most performant way to do this.

Comment: I have a question about your expected result, do you really want the date key and the date value in the same map as your  values? why can you not have a `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>` where the first map is keyed on date, and the `List<Map<>>` is your actual values?

Comment: I'll also ask, why do you need to do this with java 8 streams?  I doubt it would be more performant, and you could definitely do it in a more readable way just by hand-rolling the steps through the code.

Comment: @BeUndead not sure why you think a Java 8 solution is not readable. Not so performant, perhaps. But definitely not ugly code.

Comment: @scigs, actually a list is indeed my expect return, not a map

Comment: @BeUndead, before asking this question, I tried the for loop to do this. But the application hang when the List size is about 50 thousand. As far as I know, Java8 stream has a better performance to do this. So I ask this question. Correct me if I have a wrong conception.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, why Java8 is not so performant? Is there any better performant way to handle a huge size of this type of list?

Comment: Well, when you have 2 or more entries for the same date, you have to create a new map to hold (intermediate) results of merging maps together. There would be n - 1 maps created (e.g. one to hold results for 2 maps, 2 for merging 3 maps, one for first 2 maps and then another for merging that intermediate results with the 3rd map).

You can probably have a better Java 8 implementation if you flatMap the key/value entries of each map and put those values once in a final map for a given date.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: This was a guess as to how the implementations would look (and a quick glance at the answers so far would support this).  I can't really imagine anyone finding a stream solution _more_ readable than a `for` loop achieving the same - perhaps _as_ readable with extreme familiarity with java 8 streams, but that's rare to come by.

Comment: @BeUndead I find all the solutions pretty readable. If one wants to improve the code readability, functions could be named, e.g. `Function<Map<String, String>> classifier = (map) -> map.get("date");` and use it `Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, ...)` instead of inlining it. I agree that some things are not as readable when you first read some lambda code but if you've seen lambda code before, all solutions look good. You can't go simpler than that and I don't think a loop does much better.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, do you mean the flat map is the most performant way to handle this even though the list size is too big?

Comment: @BetterMan I've checked Eklavya's answer and it appears to be working without creating more maps than needed, just one per date, which is optimal, you can't achieve better than this.

Comment: @BetterMan I suggest you pick an answer and accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, already done this. I'm just back from a serious problem. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way using `groupingBy` and `Collector.of`

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>(before.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                k -> k.get("date"),
                Collector.of( HashMap<String,String>::new,
                        (m,e)-> m.putAll(e),
                        (map1,map2)->{ map1.putAll(map2); return map1;}
                ))).values());
```

Here, first use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by date. Then define custom collector using `Collector.of` to collect `List<Map<String, String>>` into `Map<String, String>`. After create list using map values.

And using `Collectors.flatMapping` from **Java 9**

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>(before.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                k -> k.get("date"),
                Collectors.flatMapping(m -> m.entrySet().stream(), 
                    Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey(), v -> v.getValue(), (a,b) -> a))))
               .values());
```

Answer (score 7):

```java
before
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap((m) -> m.get("date"), m -> m, (a,b) -> {
      Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
      res.putAll(a);
      res.putAll(b);
      return res;
  }))
  .values();
```

This is the solution you're looking for.

The `toMap` function receives 3 parameters:

- the key mapper, which in your case is the date
- the value mapper, which is the map itself that's being processed
- the merge function, which takes 2 maps with the same date and puts all the keys together

Output:

```
[{date=2020.1.5, A=20, B=10}, {date=2020.1.6, A=30}, {date=2020.1.7, C=30}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the very same result using a certain number of Collectors, orderly:

- `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by the date
- `Collectors.reducing` to merge the `Map<String, String>` items
- `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to transform the values from `Map<String, Optional<Map<String, String>>>`, as a result of the previous reducing to the final output `List<Map<String, String>>`.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = before.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            m -> m.get("date"),
            Collectors.reducing((l, r) -> {
                l.putAll(r);
                return l; })
        ),
        o -> o.values().stream()
                       .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

The `list` contains what are you looking for:

> `[{date=2020.1.5, A=20, B=10}, {date=2020.1.6, A=30}, {date=2020.1.7, C=30}]`

**Important:** This solution has two he disadvantages:

- It looks clumsy and might not be clear for an independent viewer
- It mutates (modifies) the original maps included in the `List<Map<String, String>> before`.

Comment: Warning: This solution mutates the original maps!

Comment: I have included the note. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
List<Map<String, String>> remapped = before.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("date")))
    .values().stream()
    .map(e -> e.stream()
               .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x1, x2) -> x1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

remapped.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
{date=2020.1.5, A=20, B=10}
{date=2020.1.6, A=30}
{date=2020.1.7, C=30}
```